# Showing that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{n!}{n^2}$ diverges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

If I have the limit
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{n!}{n^2},$$
how do I prove that limit does not converge?

I tried to find two subsequence, but could not find them. I also tried Stirling's approximation for $n!$ and I obtained the limit
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{2\pi}\frac{n^{n-\frac12}}{\mathrm e^n}$$
but I am stuck.

Comment: Use [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3084945/prove-that-n-n3-for-every-integer-n-ge-6-using-induction). Then $n!/n^2>n$ for all $n\ge 6$ and you are done.

Comment: Alternative: see [the ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you.

Comment: $n!>n(n-1)(n-2)$ if $n>3$. Hence $n!/n^2>(n-1)(n-2)/n= (1-1/n)(n-2)$. The first factor converges to $1$, the second factor diverges.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use Stirling's Formula, then note that

$$\frac{n^{n-1/2}}{e^n}=e^{-1/2}\left(\frac ne\right)^{n-1/2}$$

For $n>2e$, we have as $n\to \infty$

$$e^{-1/2}\left(\frac ne\right)^{n-1/2}>(2e)^{-1/2}(2)^n\to \infty$$

And we are done!

Comment: Was this useful?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{n!}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{(n-2)!}\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2}{(n-1)n}=0\cdot 1=0.
$$
Depending on whether one uses the extended real number $+\infty$, one may say that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{n^2}=+\infty$ or the limit of the sequence $(\sqrt{n!}{n^2})_{n=1}^\infty$ does not exist.